# React Router this.context.router.push does not remount the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

We have a click handler that updates the url using the react router 2.0 this.context.router.push().  See below:

```
selectRelatedJob(slug) {
  JobActionCreators.fetchJobPage(slug);
  JobsActionCreators.getRelatedJobs({'sl': slug});
  this.context.router.push({pathname: '/job', query: {sl: slug}});
}
```

Our goal is to fetch the new data based on the "sl" query string, but our componentWillMount() method is not being called because we are updating the url to the same path --- just a different query string.  Instead the update lifecycle methods are being called.  Our current approach is to call the action creators to fetch the data directly in the click handler.  However, this seems redundant and hacky because we have already updated the url.  Ideally, the component would get unmounted and remounted.

Here are the nested routes:

```
<Route component={App}>
  <Route path="/" component={HomePage}/>
    <Route path="job" component={JobPage}/>
    <Route path="job/" component={JobPage}/>
  </Route>
</Route>
```

What is the best case practice around navigating to the current url with a different query string?

Comment: Why unmount it? You should be able to call the action creator in 
`componentWillReceiveProps()`

Comment: So you would recommend doing a check in `componentWillReceiveProps()` to determine if the current and next query strings are equal and if not, make the call to the action creators?

Comment: Exactly! Example for accessing the query string https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/examples/query-params/app.js

Answer (score 0):

Pass in a different component.

```
<Route path="job/:id" component={JobDetailPage} />
```