# this.props.history is deprecated (react-router)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I was trying to programatically navigate to a different page like so `this.props.history.push('/new-path');` it worked, but I got a deprecation warning in console saying:

`Warning: [react-router] props.history and context.history are deprecated. Please use context.router.` more about it here https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#changes-to-thiscontext

---

Afterwards I tried to use this new method like so `this.context.router.push('/new-path')` but this doesn't seem to be the right approach.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213446/react-router-this-context-router-push-does-not-remount-the-component

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe you did forget to define the router as contextType? Assuming you have a component like:

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return <div></div>;
      }
 }
```

You have to define the contextTypes as follows right beneath your component:

```
YourComponent.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```